# how can I convert time to decimal in Swift code

Tags: ios, swift, time

punch in @ 2:00:00 and pushed out at 4:15:20, and the time calculation came out right.. Time = 2:15:20 I want to be able to multiply this with 10.50, and I'm unable to convert time to decimal so I can easily multiply it.

I've done a lots of conversations but none of them made any sense and need help...

would you please help thanks.

Comment: What is the expected result of multiplying a time value with a float ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
let startString = "2:00:00"
let endString = "4:15:20"

func secondsFromMidnight(input:String) -> Int {
    let comps = input.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    let h = (Int(comps.first!) ?? 0) * 3600
    let m = (Int(comps[1]) ?? 0) * 60
    let s = Int(comps.last!) ?? 0
    return h + m + s
}


let start = secondsFromMidnight(startString)
let end = secondsFromMidnight(endString)

let elapsedTime = Double( end - start )

let dateComponentsFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()

dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour,.Minute,.Second]

dateComponentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(elapsedTime)  // "2:15:20"

let result = elapsedTime * 10.5
```